# how to run activity only on first installation?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am using c# on developing an android application. My problem is "How will I be able to run an activity only on first installation/Run"

Is there a more efficient way?

```
 Boolean isFirstRun = GetSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", FileCreationMode.Private).GetBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

  if (isFirstRun)
  {
      //show start activity

      Intent b = new Intent(this, typeof(tutorial_data));

      StartActivity(b);
      Toast.MakeText(this, "firstrun!", ToastLength.Short).Show();

  }
  GetSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", FileCreationMode.Private).Edit().PutBoolean("isFirstRun", false).Commit();
```

On first installation the code seems to work but after opening again it just force closes...

Comment: Is there any logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an existing which seems to be working and can be found below

Declare a field:

```
  ISharedPreferences prefs = null;
```

In your OnCreate:

```
  prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

OnResume:

```
 bool vFirstRun = prefs.GetBoolean("firstrun", true);
 if (vFirstRun)
{
    *** YOUR CODE HERE ***
    prefs.Edit().PutBoolean("firstrun", false).Commit();
}
```

See to it that this code is in the activity that calls your one-time activity.